# Error using pdfx package with subcaption package (introduced by the chkfloat package)

Tags: hyperref, subcaption, pdfx

I am using `pdfx` with the `a-1b` option to comply with my university's requirements for PhD thesis.

According to the [`pdfx`](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/pdfx/pdfx.pdf) package's documentation, this package must be loaded first.

However, this produces the following error when processed by `luatex` (TL 2018)

> ! Package caption Error: The `subcaption' package does not work correctly
>   (caption)                in compatibility mode.

The `caption` package's documentation strongly discourages (to the point of scaring off the user) the use of `compatibility=false` option.  How can we get around this issue?

#### Update:

I have narrowed this down to the [`chkfloat`](https://ctan.org/pkg/chkfloat) package. The aforementioned error message shows up only when the package is loaded.

Here is a MWE to reproduce the issue.

```
\documentclass[british]{article} 
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx} 
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[margin=10pt,font=small,labelfont={bf},labelsep=quad]{caption} % for improved layout of figure captions with extra margin, smaller font than text
\usepackage{chkfloat}  % <---- Commenting this out removes all errors. If this line is included, an error '! Package caption Error: The `subcaption' package does not work correctly (caption) in compatibility mode.'
\usepackage{subcaption} 
\begin{document} 
Lorem ipsum. 
\end{document}
```

If the `\usepackage{chkfloat}` line is commented, the document compiles fine. What might be a good workaround?

Comment: Can you show a minimal example? `\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum.
\end{document}` compiles without any errors for me with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @moewe Yes, thank you for the prompt to include a `MWE`. This was tremendously useful. From my huge preamble, I have bisected and pruned off irrelevant packages, until I narrowed it down to the `chkfloat` package. I have updated the question with this information and a `MWE`.  Looks like a bug with this package.

Comment: It gets even better: The problem persists even if you don't load `pdfx`. So it has nothing to do with that. This is purely a conflict between `subcaption` and `chkfloat`.

Comment: @Krishna and exactly that is the main advantage of (really minimal) MWEs. The fact that we can only correctly help with one is only a side effect.

Comment: @moewe huh? I have been using `chkfloat` with `subcaption` for the last 4 months without any error. The error came up only today when I was trying to include the `pdfx` package to conform to my university's `PDF/A` requirements. I don't understand why I am getting a different behaviour than you. Any thoughts?

Comment: I don't know I took your MWE and deleted the `\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}` line. Then I compiled the code with LuaLaTeX and get ```Package caption Error: The `subcaption' package ...```.

Comment: @moewe whoa. You are indeed right, but the plot gets __murkier__. try adding `usepackage{hyperref}` as the last package in my `MWE`, and things work just fine!! Uncomment `hyperref` and we get the same error. This explains why I was able to successfully compile my document for the last 4 months. Any idea what is going on?

Comment: You'd have to wait for an expert to confirm this, but as far as I can see loading `hyperref` after `chkfloat` undoes some of the definitions that `chkfloat` makes (maybe even rendering it useless?). The definitions that `hyperref` uses to replace `\@caption` are compatible with the `caption` package, so it does not complain and does not go into compatibility mode. But if the definitions of `chkfloat` survive, they cause `caption` to switch into compatibility mode which does not work out well for `subcaption`. You can reproduce the error with `hyperref` if you load `chkfloat` after `hyperref`.

Comment: pdfx loads hyperref earlier (which can be a problem as you normally should load hyperref rather late) that's why you get the error when you load pdfx.

Comment: @moewe thank you for the explanation. I shall forget about `chkfloat` entirely since it looks quite buggy.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hmm.. yes, entirely agree with you. I am well aware that `hyperref` need to be loaded last (with a few exceptions). The package `pdfx` loads it right away. But the authors of `pdfx` are the venerable CVR and Han-Tha-Thanh, and they insist on loading the package upfront before anything else. This really puts me in a dilemma. What should I do? Load `pdfx` first or last?

Comment: I would try to load it later. Imho if the authors think that some code must be run early and if they want to load hyperref then they should split their package in two parts.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thank you. I think this seems like a tricky topic. In the interest of reaching out to a wider audience and getting more feedback from experts here, I am considering to post this sub-question as a new question.  The problem with loading it very late is that `pdfx` loads some important packages such as  `xcolor` which may mess up things.

Comment: Using `compatibility=false` would make the `caption` package work, but this would override the re-definition of `\@caption` and therefore disable the functionality  of the `chkfloat` package. I could offer a hack to make it work anyway, but I would prefer the proper solution: Adapt the `caption` package to the `chkfloat` package. Will do so next Sunday. Please hold the line... https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/issues/34

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt thank you very much for taking interest in this issue and offering a fix. Much appreciated.

Comment: @Krishna Didn't find time on Sunday to do the adaption, but I did it right now. See my answer.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt absolutely no problem. Much appreciate your support here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just adapted the `caption` package bundle to the `chkfloat` package:

https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/commit/e2abb8687af8d3723ac83367e1e455b3b5c1f58c

Submission of a new version of the `caption` package bundle including this fix is planned for Sunday. Until then, one can get the new files here:
https://gitlab.com/axelsommerfeldt/caption/tree/3.3/tex

If something does not work as expected, or if there are questions left, please don't hesitate to contact me (or drop a comment here).

Comment: A new version (2018-09-12) containing the bugfix was uploaded to CTAN right now.